# Show popover when focus on a textbox, hide it on blur but not if popover is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

My issue in simple terms:

- I've a text input.
- When it gains focus, a Bootstrap "popover" will appear via jquery's `.on('focus',...)`
- The popover contains a form with radioboxes

I want the Popover to hide on blur, but NOT when something is clicked inside the popover itself (otherway clicking on it will make the textbox lose focus and the popover disappears, making it useless).

Any ideas?

Comment: if you wrote the code for the popover, then just make sure it stays when the popover box is visible or has focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah HTML classes, .data(), boolean flags... Whatever suits you

```
.on('click',...){
```

1. `popover.addClass('oak');`
2. `popover.data('oak',true);`
3. `var oak = true;`

then

```
.on('click',...,function(){
   //oak = popover.hasClass('oak');
   //oak = popover.data('oak');
   if(oak) return;
   popover.hide();
});
```

Comment: I was frantically searching how to "focus" the popover... I'll guess that, more simply, "click" should do the trick :) I'll try and let you know.